# Calculating Time per person

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to build a query for a friend and I'm not 100% sure what I need to do yet. I need to calculate the total time per person over a group of tables.

The table setup looks somewhat like this....

> Participant(participant_id)
>
> TableA(participant_id, time1, time2, time3)
>
> TableB(participant_id, time1, time2, time3)
>
> TableC(participant_id, time1, time2, time3)

A participant may or may not be in every table either. For example Participant 1 may have a record in Table A, but not B or C. Also time1, time2, or time3 may be NULL.

With this given info how would I calculate the total time per person across all the tables?

> (tableA.time1 + tableA.time2 + tableA.time3) + (tableB.time1 +
>   tableB.time2 + tableB.time3) + (tableC.time1 + tableC.time2 +
>   tableC.time3)

I use more TSQL than anything, but have lots to learn. Thanks ahead of time for anyone that can give me some useful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a UNION query to unpivot and merge the tables, and then aggregate over [participant_id], something like the following (tested in Access 2010):

```sql
SELECT participant_id, SUM(time_value) AS total_time
FROM
    (
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableC
    ) AS u
GROUP BY participant_id
```

**Edit re: comment**

If you "hit a wall" on the number of UNIONS allowed in the subquery and start getting a "Query is too complex" error then a workaround would be to

- create a new empty table named [TimeValues] with columns [participant_id] and [time_value]
- load up the temporary table in batches with queries like this

```sql
INSERT INTO TimeValues (participant_id, time_value)
SELECT participant_id, time_value FROM
    (
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableB
    ) AS u

INSERT INTO TimeValues (participant_id, time_value)
SELECT participant_id, time_value FROM
    (
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time1 AS time_value FROM TableD
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time2 AS time_value FROM TableD
        UNION ALL
        SELECT participant_id, time3 AS time_value FROM TableD
    ) AS u
```

- then run the aggregation query on the temporary table.

Comment: Unfortunately, Access doesn't allow `union` in subqueries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes it does, at least in Access 2010. I just pasted that query into an Access 2010 database and it worked fine.

Comment: I do want to add that I did get 'Query is Too Complex' after adding the 5th table. What would you do in that case?

Comment: That's what I figured I would have to do. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `left join`s and a lot of addition in the `select` clause:

```
select p.particpant_id,
       (nz(a.time1) + nz(a.time2) + nz(a.time3) +
        nz(b.time1) + nz(b.time2) + nz(b.time3) +
         . . .
       ) /
       (iif(a.time1 is null, 0, 1) + iff(a.time2 is null, 0, 1) + iif(a.time3 is null, 0, 1) +
        iif(b.time1 is null, 0, 1) + iff(b.time2 is null, 0, 1) + iif(b.time3 is null, 0, 1) +
        . . .
       )
from (participant p left join
      tableA a
      on p.participant_id = a.participant_id
     ) left join
     tableB b
     on p.participant_id = b.participant_id
     . . . ;
```